# Python & MongoDb: Query not working at execution time

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a token saved in  mongo db like .

```
db.user.findOne({'token':'7fd74c28-8ba1-11e2-9073-e840f23c81a0'}['uuid'])
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5140114fae4cb51773d8c4f8"),
    "username" : "jjj51@gmail.com",
    "name" : "vivek",
    "mobile" : "12345",
    "is_active" : false,
    "token" : BinData(3,"hLL6kIugEeKif+hA8jyBoA==")
}
```

The above query works fine when i execute in the mongo db command line interface .

The same query when i am trying to run in Django view lik.

```
get_user = db.user.findOne({'token':token}['uuid'])
or `get_user = db.user.findOne({'token':'7fd74c28-8ba1-11e2-9073-e840f23c81a0'}['uuid'])`
```

I am getting an error

```
KeyError at /activateaccount/
'uuid'
```

Please help me out why I am getting this error .

**My database**

```
 db.user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5140114fae4cb51773d8c4f8"), "username" : "ghgh@gmail.com", "name" : "Rohit", "mobile" : "12345", "is_active" : false, "token" : BinData(3,"hLL6kIugEeKif+hA8jyBoA==") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51401194ae4cb51773d8c4f9"), "username" : "ghg@gmail.com", "name" : "rohit", "mobile" : "12345", "is_active" : false, "token" : BinData(3,"rgBIMIugEeKQBuhA8jyBoA==") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514012fcae4cb51874ca3e6f"), "username" : "ghgh@gmail.com", "name" : "rahul", "mobile" : "8528256", "is_active" : false, "token" : BinData(3,"f9dMKIuhEeKQc+hA8jyBoA==") }
```

Comment: Your tokens are stored as BinData(). How are they generated/inserted into the database?

Comment: @robertklep  I used python uuid  like  token =  uuid.uuid1()
            context['token'] = token  db.user.insert(context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** your query is faulty.

Longer explanation:

```
{'token':'7fd74c28-8ba1-11e2-9073-e840f23c81a0'}['uuid']
```

translates to `undefined`, because you're trying to get the property `uuid` from an object that doesn't have that property. In the Mongo shell, which uses Javascript, that translates to the following query:

```
db.user.findOne(undefined)
```

You'll get some random (okay, not so random, probably the first) result.

Python is a bit more strict when you're trying to get an unknown key from a dictionary:

```
{'token':token}['uuid']
```

Since `uuid` isn't a valid key in the dictionary `{'token':token}`, you'll get a `KeyError` when you try to access it.

**EDIT:** since you've used Python `UUID` types to store the tokens in the database, you also need to use the same type in your query:

```
from uuid import UUID

token = '7fd74c28-8ba1-11e2-9073-e840f23c81a0'
get_user = db.user.find_one({'token' : UUID(token) })
```

Comment: what is the overcoe for this

Comment: Remove `['uuid']` from your query.

Comment: Define `not working`. You can't be getting a `KeyError`, so something else. Please augment your question.

Comment: 'NoneType' object is not iterable   while doing     get_user = db.user.find_one(context)
where context['token'] = 7fd74c28-8ba1-11e2-9073-e840f23c81a0'

Comment: Well, are you sure a user with that token actually exists in the database? Try the query (without `['uuid']`) in the Mongo shell. Also, does `context` contain more items besides `token`?

Comment: I have only three listing in database i posted here please check updated question .And context contain only token